# Invalid Character Constant at ( 'node-fetch')

Tags: java

so this is my code:
My code is saying that on the 2nd line (String fetch.....) there are 2 Invalid character constants & I cant figure out how to fix this

=====================================================

```
public static void api() {

    String fetch = require('node-fetch');
    let API_FILE = require('./API_KEY.json');
    
    let API_KEY = API_FILE["API_KEY"] // API key location
    
    String playername = "Username"; // Players Username
    String playerUUID = "UUID of said username"; // Players UUID
    
    
    fetch('https://api.hypixel.net/player?key=$[API_KEY]&name=$[playername]') // Retrieves data from <-- website
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data {
        console.log(data)
        })
        .catch(error => console.log("Network Error", error))) // Informs me if anything went wrong
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't look like Java... I suspect you're getting confused between Javascript and Java. They're completely different languages.

Comment: in JAVA `'`  is used to delimit a SINGLE character, like in `'x'`, while `"`  is used to delimit a string of characters, like in `"node-fetch"` - but, as mentioned in previous comment, this code does not look like (pure) Java - `let` and `=>` are  not valid in Java, more like Javascript (AFAIK, in Javascript, strings can be also delimited by `'` ); `console.log` is also very typical for Javascript...

Comment: @user16320675 It is a javascript (!), not java lambda sign. In java, the lambda sign for the java lambda expression is `->`, which you can basically use to create an object of an anonymous interface implementation with few code.

Comment: @user16320675: You're absolutely correct, my mistake. (Comment deleted. I suspect all the comments about that could be deleted...)

Answer (score 1):

**Error #1**

In java, you can only create a `String` by putting it into `"` signs.

You can put a single character in `'` signs to create a `char`.

A `String`, e.g. "Test" consists of multiple `char`s, e.g. 'T' & 'e' & 's' & 't', so it is basically a `char[]`, which you cannot modify.

**Error #2**

The keyword `let` is not supported in java. You need to replace it with the specific type of the object you want to store. If you don't want to do that, `var` works in newer versions.

**Error #3**

Unlike in javascript, you cannot have `String`s as array indices. If you want to do that anyway, you'll have to use a `Map`:

```
Map<String, Something> map = new HashMap<>();

map.put("Test", new Something());

map.get("Test") //returns the new Something instance
```

But I don't think you want that here (`API_FILE`?)

**Error #4**

Your server request is a javascript request, which has nothing to do with java. [This](https://www.baeldung.com/java-http-request) is a tutorial about how to make server requests in java.

---

Why do you want to log player data from Hypixel?

Comment: thank you for the help, this is my first time trying to code using java / java script idk which one im using i think im using java so i was expecting quite alot of mistakes, im trying to make an AH bin flipping mod on hypixel skyblock, i was trying to see if i could get player data first since thats easier & then move onto AH data @cactusroot